# How to upload Servlet/JSP website through Amazon Web Services?

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on a Servlet/JSP project and I want to host it on aws.amazon.com. I have already signed up for Amazon Web Services and after signing in this page opens up and I have no idea what to do or which option to select.[image: Amazon Web Services Console]

I think AWS provides a lot of customization with a lot advanced technical options to choose from, but this is difficult for beginners who just want to make their site running.

My project will use these:-

1. JSP/Servlets
2. CSS
3. MySQL
4. Struts2
5. Tomcat WebServer

Comment: Go through the developer doc of AWS. There must be some kind of a walkthrough

Comment: visited this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/), but how do i know which option to choose from, apparently amazon has its own names for different services which leaves me banging my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest these approaches to study:

1. Elastic BeanStalk - This is AWS simply hosting model.  If you're not IT savy you should pursue this approach
2. EC2 with MySQL RDS - In this case you'll create a Virtual Machine(s) (EC2) install Tomcat and other dependencies and deploy your app.  You'll then use RDS to store your data (which is MySql as a service)
3. EC2 only - YOu'll do the same as 2. but install your own instance of MySql.  There may be AMI's offered that you can provision that will meet your application requirements.

Other reading:

1. Route53 if your going to use AWS for your domain records
2. Elastic Load Balancing if your going to need High Availability
3. Elastic Block Store if you want persistent disks accross VMs
4. Network Security Groups to secure your VMs (for 1. and 2.)
5. Virtual Private Cloud for additional security
6. CloudFormation if you want to automate provisioning

There are many articles on: [AWS Architecture](http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/)

Comment: in third approach you said i can install my own instance of MySql, where do one install one's own instance of mysql. do you mean outside amazon web services?

Comment: No, on an EC2 instance.  It can be the same EC2 instance you install Tomcat, or a second instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a eclipse plugin for Amazon web services.

The AWS Toolkit provides an AWS Java web project template for use in Eclipse. The template creates a web tools platform (WTP) dynamic web project that includes the AWS SDK for Java in the project's classpath. Your AWS account credentials and a simple index.jsp file are provided to help you get started. The following instructions assume you have installed both the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and the AWS Toolkit plug-in. For more information, see Setting Up the [AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup.html).

Also check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.sdlc.html) & [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/layers-java-deploy.html)

Comment: i needed to know about the services that aws provides and i am not using eclipse. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 1st approach using Beanstalk to deploy your jsp application. There you are going to leverage all the advantages of AWS like load balancing, auto scaling, ddb and DW support and many other technologies. With Beanstalk you setup dev environment on your local machine and deploy the changes in AWS and once setup is done you are done...

May be you will need to spend some time on migrating from MySQL but that will be work on longer duration when you are going to have lot of users.